# What regular expression selects a string between two "*" characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to select text between two * characters in a file and am having trouble forming the regular expression to do so.

For example with a file like the following:

```
* Apple
Are good

* Banana 
Are great

* Cauliflower 
Are bad
```

It would select 3 different groups

Apple
Are good

Banana 
Are great

and

Cauliflower 
Are bad

I believe I need to use ^ and $ for this but my selector: `^\*$\*`

is not working.

Comment: Assuming you work in single-line mode: `[*](.*?)[*$]` group 0 there will have it I suspect. Mostly just make sure to put your `*` in brackets or escape them with `\`

Comment: Why are you using `^` and `$` if you're not looking to match line beginnings/endings? And what do you think you'll match with no actual characters other than `\*` in your expression? I think you need to do some more research on regular expressions.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused how a RE like this would work. Can't I just select text after a ``"*"`` until another ``"*"`` appears

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions aren't even necessary here. Just use `str.split` and `str.strip`:

```
>>> f = '''* Apple
... Are good
...
... * Banana
... Are great
...
... * Cauliflower
... Are bad'''
>>> for line in f.split('*'):
...     if line.strip():
...             print('start')
...             print(line.strip())
...             print('end')
...
start
Apple
Are good
end
start
Banana
Are great
end
start
Cauliflower
Are bad
end
```